# I need help identifying where my null pointer exception is coming from

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0, NetBeans associated with two xhtml pages. The xhtml renders a select one radio menu from which the user may select an experiment about which they'd like more information. When they do, I'd like for the xhtml to pass the experiment back to java as a string. After the user hits submit, I'd like another xhtml page to open from which the user can further narrow their search criteria. As of right now, when the user clicks submit, there is a null pointer exception. Also, using System.out.println(), I can see that java is not getting the string back from the web page as my Glassfish server output prints (in part) : "Info:   nullaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa". It doesn't print the other println() at all.

XHTML portion

```
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="Test"  value="Please Selecte a Test">
                        <p:ajax update="Test"  partialSubmit="#{targetBeantFranz.selectedNameOfExperiments}"/>
                        <f:selectItems  value="#{targetBeantFranz.nameofexperiments}" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                    <h:commandButton value="Select" action="open" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
```

and here are the affected Java methods (The entire JAVA file is much, much longer than this):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "targetBeantFranz", eager = true)
@SessionScoped

public class TargetBeanFranz implements Serializable {

public String selectedNameOfExperiments;
private final Map<String, String> nameofexperiments;

public TargetBeanFranz() throws SQLException {

        nameofexperiments = new HashMap<String, String>();

        XYexpdataServiceAdapter xydata = new XYexpdataServiceAdapterImpl();

        List<String> dbnameofexperiments = xydata.getNameofexperiments();
        for (String ta : dbnameofexperiments) {
            nameofexperiments.put(ta, ta);
        }
    }

    public String getSelectedNameOfExperiments() {
        System.out.println(selectedNameOfExperiments + "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        return selectedNameOfExperiments;
    }

    public void setSelectedNameOfExperiments(String selectedNameOfExperiments) {
        System.out.println(selectedNameOfExperiments + "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
        this.selectedNameOfExperiments = selectedNameOfExperiments;
    }
}
    public Map<String, String> getNameofexperiments() {
        return nameofexperiments;
    }
}
```

ETA: My stacktrace looks like this:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator$MapIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:346)
    at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator$MapIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:155)
    at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.SelectUtils.matchValue(SelectUtils.java:86)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.validateValue(UISelectOne.java:153)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processValidators(Layout.java:233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Show the _complete_ stack trace and indicate in your code the line that throws the exception.

Comment: When you get a NPE, it should come with a stack trace which tells you exactly what is causing it.

Comment: @Jim Garrison Since I'm new to Java programming, it's entirely possible that the stacktrace does, in fact, indicate exactly which line is throwing the exception, but if it does, I can't tell.

Comment: `partialSubmit` accepts `true` or `false`, not a String in your bean... and... why would you update your own component after selection?

Comment: @rion18 I changed it back to listener (which is what it was before it partialSubmit), and I get the identical stacktrace.

Comment: @SheldonFan have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Comment: @Scorpion Thank you. Please, post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) for further info about JSF UI component `<h:selectOneMenu>` .

Answer (score 0):

it might be the case that u need to initialize in the bean's constructor: selectedNameOfExperiments